# Upload large file sizes error H18 Heroku PHP Laravel request interrupted

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, upload, php-ini

I don't understand how I can send a response to avoid Heroku's server error when uploading files that exceed 20mb.

I am using PHP 7.4/Laravel 8.x and I am receiving,

```
heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST
```

An H18 signifies that the socket connected, some data was sent as part of a response by the app, but then the socket was destroyed without completing the response.

It is terminating early due to Heroku's 30 second request limit.

I have configured my .user.ini file,

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_input_time = 300 
max_execution_time = 300
```

Am declaring it in the Procfile,

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -i .user.ini public/
```

I accept multiple files in my form,

```
<input style="display:none;" type="file" id="files" name="attachment[]" multiple required>
<label for="files" class="files-button" id="filesButton">Upload Images</label>
```

if the file is an image, I upload it

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // more memory

if($request->hasFile('attachment')) {
    $valid_exts = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if (in_array($extension, $valid_exts)) {
                Storage::disk('s3')->put("/model images/$url_name/",  $file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way around this 30 second forced timeout?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running up with the same problem.
As you say the connection is interrupted by a section of a large response.

> Usually, an H18 indicates that a response has multiple stages - for
> instance, streaming chunks of a large response - and that one of those
> stages has thrown an error.
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h18-server-request-interrupted

Docs suggest looking through the log files to determine which stage/chunk of the response it threw the error on and fixing that problem.

As far as configuring time out, Heroku says it's not possible.

> The timeout value is not configurable. If your server requires longer
> than 30 seconds to complete a given request, we recommend moving that
> work to a background task or worker to periodically ping your server
> to see if the processing request has been finished. This pattern frees
> your web processes up to do more work, and decreases overall
> application response times.
> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#long-polling-and-streaming-responses

And suggest using a "direct" file upload, uploading it directly to an S3 from the browser.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#file-uploads

Comment: I didn't end up having to actually implement this. But yes the answer lies in direct file uploads and properly configuring CORS and other permissions in S3.